# How to post JSON data in rocket 0.5.0-rc.1?

Tags: json, post, rust, rust-rocket

I am trying to build a POST handler, that receives JSON data with [`rocket`](https://crates.io/crates/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1) (version: 0.5.0-rc.1).

This is the code I wrote:

```rust
use rocket::{post, response::content, routes, serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct MyData {
    a_field: String,
}

#[post("/route", format = "json", data = "<data>")]
fn post_my_data(data: content::Json<MyData>) -> std::io::Result<()> { 

    Ok(())
}

#[rocket::launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
    .mount("/", routes![forster_order])
}
```

However I am unable to compile this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `rocket::response::content::Json<Order>: FromData<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:17:25
    |
17  | fn post_my_data(data: content::Json<MyData>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    |                         ^^^^^^^ the trait `FromData<'_>` is not implemented for `rocket::response::content::Json<Order>`
    | 
   ::: C:\Users\me\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\rocket-0.5.0-rc.1\src\data\from_data.rs:194:41
    |
194 |     async fn from_data(req: &'r Request<'_>, data: Data<'r>) -> Outcome<'r, Self>;
    |                                         -- required by this bound in `rocket::data::FromData::from_data`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

In the [example](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/c028d63e5ba275927424397fe9d67cfebdc138ec/examples/serialization/src/json.rs#L17) I have seen that a lifetime identifier was used on the struct, that is deserialized, but none of the types I use require lifetime identifiers, so I can't assign an identifier to my struct.

Ho can I deserialize with a struct, that does not have a lifetime identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not about lifetimes, you are using the wrong `Json` struct. You are using [`rocket::response::content::Json`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/content/struct.Json.html), this can be used to set the `Content-Type` of a response (see for example [this](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/content/index.html#example)). You want to use [`rocket::serde::json::Json`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html):

```rust
//...
fn post_my_data(data: rocket::serde::json::Json<MyData>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
//...
```

Note that you must enable the Rocket feature `json` for this to be available.